# The function starting too early

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm building a contact system usin jQuery ajax. form's div has a height, so I thought that it will be nice if when you click on the input (OnFocus), the div will become bigger and when you will scroll up or down the div will return to it's regular height. The problem is that after clicking, the div become bigger and then immediately returns to it's regular height. here is my code:

```
var big = false,
    lastpalce = "",
    position = "";

function contectboxreturn() {
    if (big) {
        $("#contact").animate({
            "height": "515px"
        }, 400);
        $("#showclosebutton").hide(fast);
        big = false;
    }
}

function contectboxresize() {
    if (!big) {
        big = true;
        lastpalce = $(this).scrollTop();
        position = $("#contact").offset();
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: position.top + "px"
        }, 400);
        $("#contact").animate({
            "height": "100%"
        }, 400);
        $("#showclosebutton").show(fast);
        $(function () {
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if (position.top != $(this).scrollTop()) {
                    contectboxreturn();
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the events that are triggering this?

Comment: @epascarello <input ... onfocus="contectboxresize()" />

Comment: create a demo. in jsfiddle.net

Comment: @charlietfl http://jsfiddle.net/GLC3N/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Big to TRUE as a callback of your animation. Like so.

```
 $("#contact").animate({
     "height": "100%"
 }, 400, function(){
     big = true;
 });
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/Ldgyj/)

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your scroll event OUTSIDE your contectboxresize() function like this:

```
var big = false,
lastpalce = "",
position = "";


$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if (position.top != $(this).scrollTop()) {
            contectboxreturn();
        }
    });
});

function contectboxreturn() {
    if (big) {
        $("#contact").animate({
            "height": "515px"
        }, 400);
        $("#showclosebutton").hide(fast);
        big = false;
    }
}

function contectboxresize() {
    if (!big) {
        big = true;
        lastpalce = $(this).scrollTop();
        position = $("#contact").offset();
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: position.top + "px"
        }, 400);
        $("#contact").animate({
            "height": "100%"
        }, 400);
        $("#showclosebutton").show(fast);
    }
}
```